# get LAN adapter MAC address and save it to a text file

Tags: networking, usb, batch-file, cmd.exe, mac-address

I have a 30 different computers in my office and i need to create a batch file, which would capture computer's LAN adapter MAC address and save it to a file. So far i have googled:

```
@wmic nic where (AdapterTypeId=0 AND netConnectionStatus=2) 
get MACAddress >> "C:\Users\addresses.txt"
```

And this code outputs:

```
MACAddress 30:F9:ED:B1:2C:99
```

What i would like to ask is: 
Is there any possibility to get the output like for example:

```
"User's john.smith MAC address is: 30:F9:ED:B1:2C:99 "?
```

Because all the MAC's will be saved to one file, and I would like to know which MAC belongs to which user. All users are in a domain. Is there any cmd code for autodecteting the user?

Also it would be wonderful, if the batch file would automatically output to a .txt file in my flash drive, because I will be plugging it into 30 different computers, and partitions have mostly different names. Is there any autodetect for that?

Comment: You could also set the .txt name to the usernames name using the variable %USERNAME% its more organized and easier to lookup. like "C:\Users\%USERNAME%.txt"

Comment: @RamonRobben thanks for advice, i wanted to store everything in one file, but this will also do the trick :) By the way, any idea how to set the path automatically so that everytime i plug my USB into different PC, the .txt file would go to my flash drive? I mean, partitions have different names on every PC..

Comment: @marco_van_cerbex `%~dp0` will give the batch files current drive and directory when you execute it, so you can use `> %~dp0addresses.txt` to write to the USB.

Comment: If it's of interest, the tools here may also be useful -  http://www.nirsoft.net/network_tools.html E.g. Wireless Network Watcher.